# Are there fine lines separating content types in databases?

Tags: database-design

Well, I have a number of different content types that I want to make available.  Some are so similar, I feel they belong in the same category.  There are columns that apply to come of the content types and not to others, though.  Should I store them all in a `nodes` table, or should I create a new table for each `content type`?  Should I break the tables up over **incompatible columns**?

Here are some examples content types: book, blog entry, ad, profile, spotlight story, archival story, static page, contact form, quiz, poll.

I've been thinking about splitting the tables up like this:

```
post: book, spotlight story, archival story, blog entry

questionnaire: quiz, poll

static: static page, profile  

ad

contact form
```

It wasn't apparent to me which method was best after reading about database normalization, unfortunately, but I had a great deal of trouble understanding anything beyond the third normal form.  What I found particularly troubling when I started reading about third normal form was that people in industry often neglect to adhere to it intentionally, for the sake of speed.  So, if anyone could use my example to bring me some clarity about what's actually reasonable, I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: It depends.

Normalization implies you'd have a table for the common properties, and separate tables for each type's unique properties. If there's a large number of common properties, and it makes sense to refer to each of the types that share those properties as the same "super type", then I prefer this.

If speed matters, you may *not* want to do this, as it will force a join every time you access one of the sub-types. Whether or not that level of tuning is meaningful depends on a bunch of things.

If each sub-type has a "small" number of unique properties, it might be just as easy to store a type and each property in a single table ("single table inheritance"), or if speed *actually* becomes an issue.

Another option is to actually do both: keep a relational model, but use triggers to keep a collection of flat data. I'm not sure that makes sense in your case, since there probably wouldn't be a "large" number of joins--but for really complicated DB models, it's handy, especially for reporting.

Comment: WOW!  I never considered just going to both extremes, Dave.  Then, I can accommodate both of my personalities! :D  The plan, man....  Follow your advises.  :)P